# Accessing button value in class without ID

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a classic asp page. The page is an admin page and needs to add and delete records from a recordset. I used a vbscript loop to print the table which looks like:

```
Do While Not commentRS.EOF
            Response.Write "<tr><td><button type='submit' class='delete' name='delete' value=" & commentRS("phrase_id") & ">Delete</button></td>"
            Response.Write "<td>" & commentRS("phrase") & "</td></tr>"
            commentRS.MoveNext
            Loop
            CloseRecordset commentRS
```

I have a hidden input type on the page called deleteVal that needs to be equal to the value of the delete button clicked, so it can be passed to a stored procedure.

```
<input type="hidden" name="deleteVal" id="deleteVal" value=0/>
```

I've tried:

```
function changeDeleteVal(thisBtn)
    {
        var delVal = document.getElementById("deleteVal").value;
        delVal = thisBtn.value;
    }
```

and

```
$(function () {
        $(".delete").click(function () {
            $("#deleteVal").val() = this.value;               
        });
    });
```

I Response.Write deleteVal and get "0/0/0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery attempt needs to be changed to work, from

```
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $("#deleteVal").val() = this.value;               
    });
});
```

to

```
$(function () {
    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $("#deleteVal").val(this.value);               
    });
});
```